# Bluetooth device name unable to resolve in Pycom

Tags: bluetooth

I am using WiPy 2.0 Pycom Board.

When trying to resolve the names of the available devices the names are not resolved properly.

```
bluetooth.resolve_adv_data(adv.data,Bluetooth.ADV_NAME_CMPL)
```

This line prints the following data.

```
None
HE<�@?�'�?
```

When print the short name

```
bluetooth.resolve_adv_data(adv.data,Bluetooth.ADV_NAME_SHORT)
```

It prints out "None"

How to get the proper name of the scanned devices. I am new to this

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using manufacturer data, we can get the proper data from the sensor.

```
mfg_data = bluetooth.resolve_adv_data(adv.data, Bluetooth.ADV_MANUFACTURER_DATA)
advData = binascii.hexlify(mfg_data)
```